# Обновление виджета при перезагрузке лаунчера

Tags: обновление, виджет

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня в программе есть виджеты. Изнутри программы управляются без проблем. На ММС (автомобильном) стоит отдельный лаунчер FCC Launcher. При его перезагрузке настройки виджета сбрасываются до дефолтных, тех, что указаны при разработке в Андроид Студио. Т.е появляется фон, меняется размер и цвет текста. Но есть проблема, при перезагрузке лаунчера, ни одна функция из AppWidgetProvider не вызывается. 
Возможно надо прописать в манифесте action, но какой?
Кто знает, помогите плиз. Это проявляется и на эмуляторе Андроид Студио, и на ММС автомобиля

Comment: В заголовке нужно заменить "обновление" на "апдейт", а "перезагрузку" на "ребут" и будет вообще класс! Русский язык, ciao!

Comment: Написано по правилам русского языка